# Can we decompose complex differential equation into two real?

Tags: analysis, complex-analysis

there is a simple system:
$$
-y''(x) = f(x)
\\
y(0) = 0
\\
y(1) = 0
$$
where $y$ and $f$ is complex function of real variable $x$.

Is it legal to decompose this functions into two real (four real for two functions) and solve two equal systems with real and imag parts?

The question is stupid, but I have never solved differential equations with a complex function before, so it seems very strange. Is it just possible to guarantee that if we add up the answer from two systems, we will get the desired complex function?

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed, because two complex numbers being equal is equivalent to their real and imaginary parts being equal, i.e.

$$z = w \iff \Re(z) = \Re(w) \land \Im(z) = \Im(w)$$

So you can set, for example, $y_r(x) = \Re(y(x))$ etc. and transform your complex DE into two real-valued DEs by looking at the real and imaginary parts separately. In some cases this will make the DE easier to solve, but in others it may actually be simpler to stay working with the complex version, and identifying which is which will depend on the context.

If $x$ were allowed to be complex, then there is an additional consideration of whether $y$ is analytic in some domain, which you would need to keep an eye on.